# C# ActionLink MVC4 - Pass multiple parameters to ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink, actionresult

--Very new to C# and MVC--

**In my Views/Tasks/Index.aspx, I have the following row / cells wrapped in a table**

```
<tr>
    <td><%:
            Html.ActionLink(
                HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#65291;"),
                "Insert",
                "Tasks",
                new { onclick = "InsertTask();" },
                new { @class = "ActionButton AddButton" }
           )
        %></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtAddName" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtAddDescription" style="width: 400px;"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtAddStarting" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtAddEnding" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
</tr>
```

**And also in that same file, I have**

```
<% if (ViewBag.Message != null) { %>
<%: ViewBag.Message %>
<% } %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function InsertTask() {
        var name =      $('#txtAddName').val();
        var desc =      $('#txtAddDescription').val();
        var starting =  $('#txtAddStarting').val();
        var ending =    $('#txtAddEnding').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "Insert/" + name + "," + desc + "," + starting + "," + ending,
            context: document.body
        }).done(function () {
            alert("done!");
        });
    }
</script>
```

**In my Controllers/TasksController.cs, I have the following ActionResult(s)**

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Create an array of tasks

        //Place task objects into variable tasks

        //Create the view model
        TaskIndexViewModel tivm = new TaskIndexViewModel
        {
            NumberOfTasks = tasks.Count(),
            Tasks = tasks
        };

        //Pass the view model to the view method
        return View(tivm);
    }


  public ActionResult Insert(string Name, string Description, String Starting, String Ending)
  {
      //Insert records to DB

      //Notify
      ViewBag.Message = "Insert Successful";

      //Return success
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
```

When I click on the ActionLink element, it

1. Does not call the JS function
2. Does call the Insert ActionResult (somehow without even passing parms?)
3. The page refresh (which I eventually want to get rid of) doesn't show
   anything for ViewBag.Message

My end goal... is to have the ActionLink call the ActionResult through AJAX / JQuery, and display a "Successful" response message... without doing a full page reload.

---

**EDIT**

---

From SLaks response, I've changed my ActionLink to the below code... And added a "return false;" to the end of my JS function.

```
            <td><%:
                    Html.ActionLink(
                        HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#65291;"),
                        "Insert",
                        "Tasks",
                        null,
                        new { onclick = "InsertTask();"  , @class = "ActionButton AddButton" }
                    )
                %></td>
```

It now calls the .CS controller ActionResponse method... but all of the parameters received are null.

Comment: BTW, you can just write `＋` in your source instead of calling `HtmlDecode`.

Comment: Tried that but my program pukes every format i try.  +("&#65291;")  --  ("+&#65291;")   --   "+&#65291"      .. etc...

Comment: No; I mean the literal character `＋`.  You don't need HTML escapes in C#; you can just write `"＋"`.

Comment: Oh gotcha.  the character i'm using is slightly different, and more bold. =P

Comment: ＋ is the character you're using.  You can write it directly in your source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return false` from the inline handler to prevent the browser from performing the default action (navigating to the link)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback... but as mentioned, very new to C# and MVC.  I have absolutely no idea where the inline handler would be.  And I believe this only solves one issue, the full page reload?

Comment: @adam: `onclick = "InsertTask();"`` is the inline handler, but it's in the wrong place.  Look at the generated source and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you, that led me in the right direction.  I'll post an update to my OP of my current code.  It's calling the function now, but none of the parameters in the ActionResult have a value.

Comment: That's not how action URLs work.  You need to either craft a URL that matches a route, or create a querystring.  Passing a `data` argument to jQuery will build a querystring for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your ajax call to this it should work:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "Tasks/Insert",
        data: { name: name, description: desc, starting: starting, ending: ending },
        context: document.body
    }).done(function () {
        alert("done!");
    });
```